# makemessages for an app installed in virtualenv

Tags: django, django-multilingual

I've installed a Django App to my virtualenv, and I would like to add extra translations to that App.

Is it possible to import the messages from an app installed in a virtualenv to my django.po in my project's `locale/pt/LC_MESSAGES` folder?

Alternatively, should I translate the 3rd party app? If so, how can I use `makemessages` to generate the messages in the app installed in the virtualenv?

Answer (score 10):

Within my project directory I make a (temporary) symlink to the app in my virtualenv and then I run the makemessages command like:

../manage.py makemessages -l nl --symlinks

After the *.po files is created I remove the symlink..

Answer (score 1):

You should probably add translations to the 3rd party app, provided they're general enough for others to re-use.

You'll want to pip install a fork of the 3rd party app's repository, with something like this (assuming git and GitHub):

```
pip install -e git://github.com/{{ username }}/{{ reponame }}.git
```

Commit and push your changes, then submit a pull request to the original repository.