# Collecting messages from 3rd party apps in Django

Tags: python, django, translation, django-i18n

How can I generate messages (manage.py makemessages) from 3rd party library which is located in virtualenv directory?

I tried simply add the messages to the .po file, but everytime I run makemessages command my translation vanishes.

Many thanks

Comment: Is this library a django app?  Is it added to INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yes and yes. Strange, huh?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`manage.py makemessages` looks only for directories under the current dir.  So you have to create symlink from 3rd party app to your project's directory:

```
ln -s ~/.virtualenvs/myvenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/app app
mkdir locale
python manage.py makemessages -l cz -s
```

Note the `-s` option. It forces `makemessages` to follow symlinks.

The other caveat is if the `app` is already localized then `.po` file will be created under `app/locale/cz` directory instead of your `locale`.

Comment: And if I remove the symlink and re-make messages again, will they disappear from the .po file?

Comment: Yes, they will disappear. To prevent this move translation from `locale` dir to some other directory and set `LOCALE_PATHS` setting. Next time you run `makemessages` this translation will be untouched.