# Is it safe to edit the django-allauth translation files?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I want to edit the django-allauth translation files.

When I first opened the **en** django.po file, PyCharm gave the message: This file does not belong to the project.

If I edit the file, is it going to cause problems that I don't want or can I edit the translation without messing something up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LOCALE_PATHS setting takes highest precedence in choosing translation. Therefore if you copy the translation files for your locale into some local directory and point LOCALE_PATHS there, you can edit as you need (and then compilemessages) and django will use those.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52004442/2135738) for an example folder structure.