# Django. How localize imported python package?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, localization, gettext

There is a django project that uses localization (internationalization or multiple languages). For Django everything is well described in docs and works well. But the project uses a Python package that is installed in the system and is imported in some places as needed.

```
from aromodule import clChart as ch clAnalyse as an
```

Package is mine and I can change code. It is several Python modules(files .py) with classes that implement all sorts of mathematical calculations. Strings(words) there are there too and I want the package returns data in the locale that is currently active in Django.
Package is not localized at all. Question is how to localize it. What code should I use? Maybe add something to `__init__.py`?
Help please, despite of huge amount of various samples in the net, I did not find something similar to my case.

Comment: I'm just looking for similar problem, I am using django axes to control login attempts, but I don't know how to translate this models :(

Comment: Seems like this way with symlinks to thirdparty app working. I had to localize .po file in django axes directory, I had to copy all new generated items from axes .po file into my .po file and this working for me, reference is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20331816/7420836